# How can I choose picture from android gallery using Nativescript?

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have been browsing Nativescript website and did not manage to find a way to get a picture locally from my phone. If anyone knows a way to do it on both android and ios I would be really glad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you could use `file-system` [module](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/file-system) and native code to access the external storage from your device. you can get the path to the file and open it with the NativeScript `file-system` api. I am attaching sample example how you could get the path os an image from the **Camera Roll** storage. You could also review the article [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html), where has been described, what you could access from android device storage.

typescript

```
 import {path} from "file-system";

 var tempPicturePath = path.join(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath(), "20160719_155053.jpg");
    console.log("extr storage "+tempPicturePath);
```

javascript

```
var file_system_1 = require("file-system");

var tempPicturePath = file_system_1.path.join(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath(), "20160719_155053.jpg");
        console.log("extr storage " + tempPicturePath);
```

Comment: What if I want to let the user browse through his gallery and choose a picture ?

Comment: For this purpose you could use nativescript-imagepicker plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-imagepicker . You could also review sample project here - https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload , where have been shown, how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Nick, I supposed you want to user choose the images from gallery, right? I get this done with this nativescript plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-imagepicker

```
import * as imagepicker from "nativescript-imagepicker";

let context = imagepicker.create({
    mode: "single" // use "multiple" for multiple selection
});

context
    .authorize()
    .then(function() {
        return context.present();
    })
    .then(function(selection) {
        selection.forEach(function(selected) {
            // process the selected image
        });
        list.items = selection;
    }).catch(function (e) {
        // process error
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but, it is opening the file library, not the image gallery.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://whatwebcando.today/camera-microphone.html, you can just use a plain HTML-Input field.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Pressing the button on the mobile device opens the gallery incuding a live camera picture option and the file browser ( [Anroid (Mi9T) behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z6ec.jpg) ).

Hope this answer does not miss your point   ;-)